# new Array(_).fill(object) does not create new instances of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

ES6 allows us to fill an `Array` with a certain value:

```
function emptyRow() {
    return new Array(9).fill(0);
}
```

This function returns an `Array` of length 9, filled with only zeros:

```
>> emptyRow()
<< Array [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
```

Now I want to generate an `Array` that is filled with nine of those empty rows.

```
function emptyMatrix() {
    return new Array(9).fill(emptyRow());
}
```

However, instead of `fill` calling `emptyRow()` nine times, it seems to call it once and fills the new `Array` with nine references to the object created by `emptyRow()`. Naturally, if I change a value within any of those sub-arrays, the value is changed at the same index for all sub-arrays.

Is there a way to create a new object for each entry?

Comment: use `[...Array(9)].map(emptyRow)`

Comment: You're using a single array as the value for `fill`, meaning it will fill the array with the same array nine times, and arrays are objects, meaning they are passed by reference of a value, so basically you end up with the same array nine times.

Comment: Thanks @Guedes, that's what I needed.

Comment: Madara's answer is preferable than mine (because of compatibility), anyways I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array#fill` won't help you, it accepts the value returned by `emptyRow()`, the already created object. You could use `Array#map` which accepts a function, although you won't be able to use the `new Array()` constructor. Here's the simplest way:

```
function emptyMatrix() {
  Array.apply(null, {length: 9}).map(emptyRow);
  // create the array            fill in values
}
```

Or, more generally:

```
function generateArray(n, valueFactory) {
  return Array.apply(null, {length: n}).map(valueFactory);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively `Array.from({length: 9}, emptyRow)`

Answer (score 1):

An other solution with **map()**:

```js
var line = new Array(9).fill(0);
var matrix = line.map(x => new Array(9).fill(0))
console.log(matrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function emptyMatrix(length) {
  var matrix = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    matrix[i] = new Array(length).fill(0)
  return matrix

}
console.log(emptyMatrix(5))
```

You can set length of your matrix

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to create arrays of any length you want, and initialize them:

```js
const createMatrix = (x, y) => Array.from({ length: x }, () =>
  Array.from({ length: y }, () => 0)
);

const result = createMatrix(9, 5);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to generate an array of specific length, and then [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to fill it with empty rows:

```js
const emptyRow = () => Array(9).fill(0);

const generateArray = (n, valueFactory) => Array.from({length: 9}).map(valueFactory);

console.log(generateArray(9, emptyRow));
```